# $window.location will not reload page, Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to reload my admin page and I know angular has `$window.location.reload()` and `$route.reload()`. I tried using `$window.location.reload()` by injecting `$window` into the params of the function

```
scope.uploadList = function($window) { 
 //...
 $window.location.href = /#/admin';
}
```

underneath the success flash message but I still receive an error that says

```
Cannot read property `location` of `undefined`.
```

Not sure where to go from here. I've added this within the directive.

Comment: Are you sure that you are injecting `$window` into your directive successfully?

Comment: Why not use $location.path?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to inject the `$window` in the controller and not in the method and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should inject `$window` in controller code like below

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
      $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
      };
    }]);
```

Not in function though !!

Comment: I get a success which is great but the item I'm trying to fetch still does not show unless I reload the page. Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the item ? Can you show me the code for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$location`. This is built in with angularjs and is used for navigation. Make sure to inject it as a dependency.

```
$location.path('/admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$window` is not the object that you need to use global reference

```
 window.location.href = '/#/admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject $window into any of your controller, like so: you'll then have access to the browser window object.

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$window', function($window) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.hello = 'Hello, Universe!';
      $window.alert(hello);
      $window.location.reload();
      $window.location.href = '/#/admin';
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use $location.path("url) but it doesn't do anything if you are already on that particular page so I made a second route in routing.js that goes to the same page in affect "reloading" the page. I'm not sure if this is what you are going for though.

example:

```
        .when('/Login',
        {
            templateUrl: 'Partials/LoginCustomer.html',
            controller:'loginController'    
        })
        .when('/Login2',
        {
            templateUrl: 'Partials/LoginCustomer.html',
            controller:'loginController'    
        })
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new route you can force it to reload